# tensorflow-gpu via pip time out

Tags: pip, tensorflow

I was getting time outs from pypi.python.org when running pip install --upgrade tensorflow_gpu, so I added the --verbose and --timeout 10000 params to it. It starts out fast then begins to crawl:

```
1% |▌                               | 747kB 244bytes/s eta 2 days, 9:31:36
```

Is there a better way to install tensorflow-gpu when inside a virtualenv in Windows? Following the instructions from this model: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/attention_ocr

Comment: After about 20 attempts over 36 hours... this is now fixed. Not sure what was going on, but now it installs in ~90 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to install tensorflow within an environment is as follows.

1. Activate/Enter your python environment (e.g. for Anaconda,
   activate envName).
2. Ensure that you are actually in your virtual/conda environment!
3. Use pip to install tensorflow. For CPU use `pip install tensorflow` and for GPU use `pip install tensorflow-gpu`. Don't have both installed in the same directory.
4. Pip should take care of the rest. Tensorflow will be downloaded along with it's dependencies from Pypi.

If you're having problems installing from pip you can try updating pip or checking your internet connection. There is also a chance that Pypi are having some minor issues on their end.

Don't forget to activate your environment before trying to import Tensorflow!

Good luck!

Comment: In the example above, I was inside a virtualenv I created for this. It just kept timing out until I added the --timeout param. Not sure why it finally worked, it took ~20 tries. Out of curiosity, I tried again outside of virtualen because my native install is still on 1.2.0. I get the same error I list here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11253
THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE

so problem with 1.2.1, or problem with pip... I do not know.

Comment: Not sure. I know there were some build issues in the last couple of days so 1.2.1 might be wonky and/or pip might have an issue. I've just tried in one of my testing environments and i've downloaded 1.2.1 with no issues at good speeds etc. I think you may have got unlucky and/or your internet connection might have been an issue. Perhaps you are operating through a proxy and pypi had a problem with it. Not sure tbh. I think we'd have heard if Pypi went down for 36 hours.

Comment: Interesting, so must somehow be on my end. I do not have the fastest internet: http://beta.speedtest.net/result/6430541487.png  .. but it should easily be sufficient for 51mb. Right now I show: Downloading tensorflow_gpu-1.2.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl (51.3MB)
    3% |#                               | 1.6MB 750bytes/s eta 18:23:10   ouch.

Comment: Very strange. Unless the local server hosting Pypi/packages for you in Texas is slowed down I don't see what else the problem would be. I've just downloaded in about a minute. Don't think there's much more to this issue that can be dealt with here.